# FirebaseAuth still coming null in Kotlin Firebase Retrofit Room App

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I was developing an App in Kotlin, where I implement Firebase Retrofit and Room library for differents purposes.

So my problem comes when I try to called the FirebaseUser, in order to search into the room database, where is saved the user name, and load the information regarding him/her.

My firebase user is null, regardless how much wait.

The fragment where the exception occurs is this:

DiaryFragment.kt

```
class DiaryFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_diary), AdapterDetail.OnItemClickListenerDiary{

    private var _binding: FragmentDiaryBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private lateinit var user: String
    private lateinit var viewModel : DiaryViewModel
    private lateinit var mAuth : FirebaseAuth
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context!!);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        _binding = FragmentDiaryBinding.bind(view)

        //TODO(Use ViewModel to recover the data.)
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        val adapter = AdapterDetail(this)
        //Set the ViewModel of the DiaryFragment.
        //TODO(Solucionar NullPointerException)
        //TODO(FirebaseUser llega null )
        user = mAuth.currentUser?.email.toString()
        checkUser(user, adapter)
       /*viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[DiaryViewModel::class.java]*/
        val btnRetryDiary = binding.btnRetryDiary
        btnRetryDiary.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            checkUser(user, adapter)
        })

    }
    fun checkUser(user:String, adapter: AdapterDetail){
        if(user!="null"){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Already Sign in !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            viewModel = DiaryViewModel(context?.applicationContext as Application, RoomUnsplashPhoto(10,"null",null,null,user))
            viewModel.getPhotoUser(user)!!.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){
                adapter.submitData(viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle, it as PagingData<UnsplashPhoto>)
                binding.apply {
                    recycleViewDiary.setHasFixedSize(true)
                    recycleViewDiary.itemAnimator = null
                    recycleViewDiary.adapter = adapter
                }
            }
            setHasOptionsMenu(true)
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(context, "¡¡ User esta a null !!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
    override fun onItemClick(photo: UnsplashPhoto) {
        val action = DiaryFragmentDirections.actionDiaryFragmentToDetailFragment(photo)
        findNavController().navigate(action)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

my app build.gradle regarding firebase is this is this:

```
 //Firebase
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.4.1')

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
```

If you can help take thank in advance !

Comment: *The fragment where the exception occurs is this*. What is the exact Exception are you talking about?

Comment: The exception doesn't throw due to null check of the FirebaseUser, which a use as atribute in my Room database. The problem is Firebaseauth.getInstance() is always null

Comment: Are you sure you are authenticated? Most likely you're not, hence that NPE, right?

Comment: I'm using 2 providers to authenticate, Google, and Email and both works fine, even when I debug, the user set correctly using the email of the provider. So yes, the auth is working